# Plotting complex values in real plane with colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, complex

I have a set of data and I would like to plot it. Data looks like this `{{1,z1}, {2,z2},..., {n,zn}}`. However, the values of `z1,.., zn` can be complex also. Is there a way to give all the complex values same color but different from real values.
To be precise, I will have 2D plot, where `y` values are given by `z1,.., zn` and `x` values are just natural numbers from `1` to `n`.
Is there a way to plot this on 2D eventhough `z1,.., zn` can be complex. Like complex values with one kind of color and real with one kind of color.

I am sorry if this has already been asked.

Comment: This seems like a a duplicate, but most of the other deal with `{z1, z2 , z3 ... }`  instead of  `{{x1, z1}, {x2, z2} , {x3, z3} ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
data = N@Table[{k, Complex[Sin[2 π k/100], Cos[2 π k/100]]}, {k, 100}];
```

Now you can separate the [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html)al and [`Im`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im.html)aginary

```
ListPlot[
 {
  MapAt[Re, data, {All, 2}]
  , MapAt[Im, data, {All, 2}]
  }
 ]
```

or

```
ListPlot[
 MapAt[#, data, {All, 2}] & /@ {Re, Im}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]